# Google glass Immersive app icon doesn't show

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

My app icon has disappeared, I've sourced it to the activity alias's I am using.  I want them to display as sub menu voice commands so in the manifest I've added the VOICE_TRIGGER action. When I remove this the icon re-appears.

Any ideas for a work around?

Here'a an example of an alias:

```
    <activity-alias
        android:label="@string/do_thing"
        android:name="@string/do_thing"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        android:immersive="true"
        android:targetActivity="com.x.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
    </activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the text of the menu item is too long? I have had this before and with a long text, my icon also disappeared. When I shortened the menu text, the icon appeared again.

Comment: Nice idea, just tried it and it didn't work. Plus it wouldn't explain why removing the voice commands in the alias's fixes the bug.

Comment: My app icons were available as of XE18.11, but are gone in XE18.3.  It appears the Glass team changed something because the icons for my other sideloaded apps are also gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to use the voice command in here:
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command

if you use the your own voice command, the icon won't show on XE18.3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue with 18.3 (https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=559) and was indicated fixed around July 8th.

So hopefully you aren't seeing this anymore in any release past 18.3.